# Cordova Hybrid Mobile App - How do I access the value of a resource specified in strings.xml in my index.html page

Tags: cordova, hybrid-mobile-app, resourcestring

I am a newbie to Hybrid mobile app development and am using Cordova. I have created a simple app with index.html and related .js and .css files. Now I have added a resource string 'pagetitle' in strings.xml and I need to retrieve the value and display it in HTML. Any pointers in this regard would be greatly appreciated.

I have worked on native app Android development and have accessed resources from strings.xml, for e.g. in my case it would be '@string/pagetitle'. But now since I am developing a hybrid app and have only HTML, CSS, JS to develop.

Comment: Do you want to support i18n?

Comment: Not as of now. Right now I only need to be able to access values defined in strings.xml, within my hybrid app code.

Comment: Do you have already custom strings in the strings.xml? Or just need to show them?

Comment: This is my strings.xml. I now need to display the value of 'pagetitle' in my HTML page.                                                                                                     <resources>
    <string name="pagetitle">Title from Resource File</string>
</resources>

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

It seems that the plugin is used for the native part as explained here:

> This plugin helps you to manage string files that you need natively,
>   namely on Localizable.strings and InfoPlist.strings on iOS, and
>   strings.xml on Android.

So for the i18n, you will need external library like [LocalePlanet](http://www.localeplanet.com/api/index.html) whci you can use like this: `_('Hello, world!')`

---

**Old Answer**

No need to add it in the strings.xml. Just use the string as it is. If you add it there, then the iOS won't work properly. example: `My Page Name

If you still want to support the i18n, then you can check this [Cordova plugin](https://github.com/kelvinhokk/cordova-plugin-localization-strings). But instead of string.xml, it will be from json file.

Comment: Thank you. Yes I would need iOS too, so will check out the plugin you have mentioned. Have a doubt in it, how do I refer the variables defined in the json file in my HTML? For e.g. if I have PAGE_TITLE in my json file, how do I get its value in my HTML/

Comment: I'm sorry about the wrong Cordova plugin. This plugin actually used for native strings. Check my updated answer

Comment: After checking both options, the localization plugin is what seems best suited to my requirement. But I am still stuck at the core issue of how to access the strings defined in .json (which are then pushed into the plist and strings.xml files) in my cordova code.